# Google Site Search: how to sort results by attribute value?

Tags: google-search, google-search-api

I've successfully set up Google Site Search on my web application. Check out this sample query:

http://www.jungledragon.com/search?cx=005219266784322094156%3Ai-ruvpoc9lm&cof=FORID%3A9%3BNB%3A1&ie=UTF-8&q=monkeys&sa=Search

As you can see, the results are quite rich and fully customized. If I detect that a search results is an image, tag, photo list or user, I display a rich search result. For all other types of pages, I display a classic result (link + title). I have accomplished this using the Google XML Search API.

The next improvement I want to make is to give image results precedence. If the results have any images, those should be displayed first. Google recommends to enrich my pages with custom data to provide some structure into their indexing, so I have added this on all pages that are images:

```
<meta name="pagetype" content="image">
```

(note: not yet on the live site, only on my dev machine for now)

Once I put this live and wait for Google's bot to spider these pages again, I can refer to this extra data to enforce a certain sorting, or so I hope. I would have to append this to the XML search query:

```
&sort=pagetype
```

The problem is, I want to order by **attribute value**, not the attribute itself. How do I make sure pagetype=image comes before the other pagetypes?

If not possible, my thinking is that I should instead create a meta field called "pageorder" and set it to 1 for image pages and a higher number for others.

What do you think?